# Map Dictionary with list of elements

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible with Fluent NHibernate to map a property with the following signature?

```
IDictionary<NavigationType, IList<NavigationActionEntity>> NavigationActions;
```

`NavigationType` is an enum, `NavigationActionEntity` is a mapped entity.
I tried it like this:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.NavigationActions).AsEntityMap()
                                       .Table("CarrierNavigationActions");
```

But it is giving me an exception:

```
An association from the table CarrierNavigationActions refers to an unmapped
class: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Dal.Entities.NavigationActionEntity]]
```

Comment: I would say ... really short answer - No, not without jumping hoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a hoop to jump through

```
class ActionsHolder
{
    protected IList<TypeToEntity> innerList { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<NavigationType, IList<NavigationActionEntity>> NavigationActions
    { get { return new NavigationTypeMap(innerList); } }
}

class TypeToEntity
{
    public virtual NavigationType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual NavigationActionEntity NavigationActionEntity { get; set; }
}

class MyClassMap : ClassMap<ActionsHolder>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        HasMany(Reveal.Member<ActionsHolder, IEnumerable<TypeToEntity>>("innerList"))
            .Table("NavTypeToNavActionEntity")
            .Component(c =>
            {
                c.Map(x => x.Type);
                c.References(x => x.NavigationActionEntity).Not.LazyLoad();
            })
            ;
    }
}

class NavigationTypeMap : IDictionary<NavigationType, IList<NavigationActionEntity>>
{
    private IList<TypeToEntity> innerList;

    public NavigationTypeMap(IList<TypeToEntity> innerList)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.innerList = innerList;
    }
    // TODO: implementation of IDictionary<>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go with a simple entity in between. That looks like overkill...